# How do you set the title for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab based app and I am trying to change the title of the UINavigationBar, when a button is clicked which loads up a new Uiview but nothing shows !

I create the bar like this:

```
navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 60)];
navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.082 green:0.118 blue:0.141 alpha:1.0];
navBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navBar.translucent = NO;
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
```

Then in the method i try change:

```
UIView *sendASongView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[sendASongView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 60, screenWidth, screenHeight-110)];
[sendASongView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:sendASongView];
navBar.topItem.title = @"Send";
```

Comment: You should create a `UINavigationController` and use it as the container of your viewController. Then you can set title `self.title = @"Send"`.

Comment: @KudoCC please could you show me how its done ? im quite new to ios, Thanks !

Comment: How you make and add a `UINavigationController` to your app really depends on the rest of your app. If you creating the tab bar controller in a storyboard, you should just add a nav controller as one of the tabs.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or xib or neither ?

Comment: @KudoCC none, doing everything programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UINavigationController and use it as the container of your viewController.

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    self.statusLabel.text = @"You're logged in as";

    HomeNavViewController *profileviewController = [[HomeNavViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: profileviewController] ;


    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];

}
```

Override the method `viewWillAppear`in `YourViewController`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated] ;
    self.title = @"Sender" ;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a better idea to set the title in an `init` method or the `viewDidLoad` method of `YourViewController`. The problem with putting it in `viewWillAppear:` is that the title can get reset if the view controller appears more than once in its lifetime.

Comment: @kudoCC I only want this nav bar present after my login screen what do i do ?

Comment: @Pizzy213codes Can you show your code how you present the viewcontroller so I can modify based on it.

Comment: @KudoCC its missing vc, whats vc ?

Comment: @Pizzy213codes vc is profileviewController, my mistake.

Comment: @KudoCC yea i figured :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see a title with your `UINavigationBar` is because the navbar has no items so `topItem` is `nil`.

You need to create and set a `UINavigationItem`.

```
navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 60)];
navBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.082 green:0.118 blue:0.141 alpha:1.0];
navBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navBar.translucent = NO;

UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send"];
navBar.items = @[ item ];

UIView *sendASongView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[sendASongView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 60, screenWidth, screenHeight-110)];
[sendASongView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:sendASongView];
```

Of course it is probably a better idea to put your view controller in a `UINavigationController` but the above explains the cause of your problem.